# Why did I earn reputation because of a tag?

Tags: support, tags, reputation

I've been reading all over the site to find the answer but can't find it. I don't see what I did to earn it, but thanks anyhow!

It says: "Reputation gained on this tag..." when I hover over the tag "user-account" listed in my Reputation Tab.

Comment: You didn't gain reputation *because* of the tag, you gained reputation ***in*** a tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### It says: "Reputation gained on this tag..."

> when I hover over the tag "user-account" listed in my Reputation Tab.

I presume you are talking about hovering here?

[image]

Your **top tag** is [user-accounts](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/user-accounts) so it is showing you the rep you have gained from questions (and answers if you had any) that contain this tag.

It is your **top tag** because you have asked two questions with that tag. All the other tags appear in only one question.

[image]

You can earn badges for [tag reputation](https://superuser.com/help/badges):

[image]

Ignore the green ticks - they are displayed because I have many of these badges.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're talking about this thing in the Reputation section of the Activity page (I'm mousing over the `+213`):

[image: top tag]

Just participating in the tag didn't give you rep; it's telling you how much rep you got because of good posts you made with that tag. Those points were already included in your total rep.

<sup>The original content of this answer follows.</sup>

---

To be honest, I'm not sure what you mean. You can earn rep from edits to tag wikis and by edits to other people's normal posts (which could involve retagging), but from your [public reputation history](https://superuser.com/users/127470/teajay?tab=reputation), it doesn't look like either of those things happened. Here's what I can see:

1. You started with 1 rep, like all new users
2. You received three upvotes on [this question](https://superuser.com/users/127470/teajay?tab=reputation) for a total of +15 → rep total then 16
3. You [accepted an answer](https://superuser.com/help/badges/10/scholar?userid=127470) on that question for +2 → rep total then 18
4. Over the next few days, you got three more upvotes on that question and one on [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/860201/how-to-recover-deleted-photos-from-samsung-phone) for +20 → rep total then 38
5. You received one upvote (+5) and one downvote (-2) on [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1056490/380318) for +3 → rep total then its current value of 41

Interestingly, [your first question](https://superuser.com/q/410603/380318) no longer has an accepted answer. I don't know whether you unaccepted it, or whether the accepted answer was deleted for reasons of moderation (e.g. via Low Quality Posts review). I was under the impression that the +2 you got for accepting an answer is automatically taken away when the question stops being accepted, but that does not seem to have happened here. I suspect those two points may vanish somtime in the future, or the next time you visit https://superuser.com/reputation.

I think that accounts for the two points not associated with a post in your rep history.

Comment: The accepted answer seems to have been deleted. It was link only and not very good

Comment: @ Ben Thanks! I added info to my question to describe it. If I could snip a picture of it I would.

Comment: @TeaJay Ah, thank you. I've updated my answer.